# Rails App doesn't work on production enviroment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

I have a rails app set up with Nginx + Passenger. When i have rails_env development; on my nginx.conf everything works fine, but when I remove it so the app get server on production env it just doesnt work, seems like its not loading gems or something. Feel free to take a look at the  errors here [www.luisurraca.co.cc](http://www.luisurraca.co.cc)

```
error message:
undefined method `has_attached_file' for #<Class:0x00000003b0be10>
Exception class:
NoMethodError
```

Right now its referring to the paperclip gem, but if i start removing gems from the gemfile it will display error from some other gem and so on.

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: Maybe your gems are not installed correctly. Try a `gem list` and see if `carrierweave/paperclip/whatever you are using` is installed.

Comment: /home/ubuntu/projects/hippie-store# gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activemodel (3.2.6)
activerecord (3.2.6)
activesupport (3.2.6)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.0)
cocaine (0.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
mime-types (1.19)
multi_json (1.3.6)
tzinfo (0.3.33)

Comment: I dont see the gems installed, I ran bundle install --deployment

Comment: Are you using RVM? Maybe there is a conflict between your gemsets and your global gems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably defined paperclip/whatever in development group and it is not installed with `bundle install --deployment`. To see installed gems do `bundle show` not `gem list`.

did you specify ruby path for nginx? it should look like this:

```
    http {
        passenger_root /home/rlisowski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.13;
        passenger_ruby /home/rlisowski/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby; 
        # ....
```

Comment: I ran bundle show and paperclip is being listed as an installed gem

Comment: try run app on your own machine in production mode, check if the effect is the same

Comment: can you show us first 10 lines `hippie-store/app/models/store.rb` file?

Comment: `class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, :dependent => :destroy
  attr_accessible :address, :description, :fbook, :image, :mainphoto, :name, :logo, :phone1, :phone2, :pinterest, :images_attributes, :tags, :twitter, :web
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
   has_attached_file :mainphoto,
                     :storage => :s3,
                     :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                     :url  => '/mainphoto/:basename.:extension',
`

Comment: I feel tho, that this have something to do with RVM and the gems, because everything work all right when i set rails_env development in the nginx conf.

Comment: you can try to install gems in system with `bundle install --system` and you should see these gems with `gem list` but I don't see any  dependencie between rvm and rails_env

Comment: I ran bundle install --system and now its another gem that is having issue... looks to me that nginx is using the ruby from the system instead of the rvm ruby. Could not find polyamorous-0.5.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)